# How to display HTML in AJAX JavaScript and call it into id HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I try putting the HTML in the AJAX to display into the Bootstrap modal but the class is not working. I don't know where the error lies.

This is my code:

```
var all_gaugeKritis5 = "";
all_gaugeKritis5 += '<div class="pie-progress pie-progress-sm" data-plugin="pieProgress" data-valuemax="100" data-barcolor="#57c7d4" data-size="100" data-barsize="10" data-goal="100" aria-valuenow="86" role="progressbar" style="width: 100px;"><span class="pie-progress-number blue-grey-700 font-size-20">' + data.data10['DEVIASI'] + '</span></div>';

$('#all_gaugeKritis5').html(all_gaugeKritis5);
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="all_gaugeKritis5" class="gaugeKritis"></div>
</div>
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the `AJAX` call and how you are dealing with the response please? Also can you explain what you mean by *"the class is not working"* Not working how? not being displayed at all? The more clear you can be with your question the easier it is to explain the reason for things not functioning as intended and offer a detailed answer/demo. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try it like this?

```js
$(function() {

  ForHTML = {
    MyHTML : function() {
    var mystring = 'foo';
    var all_gaugeKritis5 = '';
   all_gaugeKritis5 += '<div class="pie-progress pie-progress-sm" data-plugin="pieProgress" data-valuemax="100" data-barcolor="#57c7d4" data-size="100" data-barsize="10" data-goal="100" aria-valuenow="86" role="progressbar" style="width: 100px;">' +
                         '<span class="pie-progress-number blue-grey-700 font-size-20">' + mystring +'</span>' +
                     '</div>';
                        $('#all_gaugeKritis5').html(all_gaugeKritis5);
    }
  }

  ForHTML.MyHTML();

});
```

```css
.pie-progress {
  color: #08c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <div id="all_gaugeKritis5" class="gaugeKritis"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you not explain the changes you have made and the reason(s) why it might be of any help? Some people wish to learn from answers rather than using copy/paste without understanding the changes....

Comment: The `error` on my side is that i dont have any data so I will just make a sample snippet

Comment: I did an `onload` only, you can `button` if you want to try, I just changed `data[]` to `mystring`

Comment: This is also using `jQuery` which isn't tagged.

Comment: the value can appear but the class still does not work,

Comment: @NewToJS in his sample he uses `$('#all_gaugeKritis5')` it is a `jquery` type

Comment: @GGw So he does. My apologies! *Hides face in shame* Can't believe I didn't notice that. I would still recommend you explain the changes you have made and the reason/benefit of them if you want to make your answer more solid.

Comment: @sayyidmahdy can you add your css in your question?

Comment: @NewToJS if only he puts his `css` i think we will know what is the problem

Comment: @GGw Maybe... the question is still rather broad and lacking relevant source code (Ajax Call) and detail of current + expected output. This might end up being a unsolved question if the relevant information isn't added.

Comment: @NewToJS also maybe because of the `jquery` versions, and right he didnt make a proper questions, if only we know the `source code` it would be easier.